# SQL syntax error when creating a function

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION NodeState ( current_time DATETIME,  lastcheck DATETIME, polling_time INT )
RETURNS varchar(20)

BEGIN

    DECLARE node_state VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT grey;
    DECLARE time_gap DATETIME; 
    SET time_gap = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, current_time, lastcheck);
    SET perc =  polling_time*0.05;

    if time_gap > perc then 
        SET node_state = 'red';
    ELSEif time_gap = perc then 
        SET node_state = 'orange';
    ELSEif time_gap – lastcheck < perc then 
        SET node_state = 'green';
    END IF;

   RETURN node_state;

END; //
```

I'm trying to create this function and I went line by line but I can't find the error.

The error I get is 1064 (42000)

Comment: What is the error message if you get a syntax error?

Comment: DEFAULT grey -> 'grey'?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the name of the current_time parameter, since there is a current_time() function and mysql may not be able to distinguish at certain locations in your code if your code refers to the parameter or the function.

Comment: I already changed that and I still get this error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE FUNCTION NodeState ( current_time2 DATETIME, lastcheck DATE' at line 1

Comment: Ok, I didn't declare perc... But I still get the error